# i have searched for my answer in stackoverflow but i cant find it and i myself tried it about an hour for relevant answer

Tags: java, jvm, javadoc

this is actually a multiplication of matrices....

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class MatMu {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        int a[][] = new int[3][3];
        int b[][] = new int[3][3];
        int c[][] = new int[3][3];
        System.out.println("enter the first matrix:");
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
            for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
                a[i][j] = input.nextInt();
        System.out.println("enter the second matrix:");
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
            for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
                b[i][j] = input.nextInt();

        System.out.println("matrix mutiplication is as follows:");
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
                c[i][j] = 0;
                for (int k = 0; k < 3; k++) {
                    c[i][j] += a[i][k] * b[k][i];
                }
            }
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
                System.out.println(a[i][j] + "\t");
            }
            System.out.println("\n");
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
                System.out.println(b[i][j] + "\t");
            }
            System.out.println("\n");
        }
        System.out.println("\n");
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
                System.out.println(c[i][j] + "\t");
            }
            System.out.println("\n");
        }
    }
}
```

the error is at `a[i][j]=input.nextInt()` and `b[i][j]=input.nextInt()`: cannot find symbols.... and this is a java program and I can't find the symbol i.e., a and b

Comment: IMHO this is one of the worst question formatting I have seen on SO.

Comment: What did I just read?...

Comment: @CrystalMeth Believe me, there have been worse. This one at least contains an implied question.

Answer (score 1):

You have not defined input which i guess is a `Scanner` before its first use. Define this scanner at the start and then use it.

Answer (score 1):

you are accessing scanner object without initializing on top of code :

```
Scanner input=new Scanner(System.in);
```

write code like That:

```
 public static void main(String args[])
            {
         Scanner input=new Scanner(System.in);
     /* your code */

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class MatMu {
public static void main(String args[]) {
    int a[][] = new int[3][3];
    int b[][] = new int[3][3];
    int c[][] = new int[3][3];


    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);  // pasted it here
    System.out.println("enter the first matrix:");

    // your code

    //  Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);  // moving this line to top

    // your next code...
}
```